# Preg_replace, please little support?

Tags: php, html-parsing, preg-replace

So i have this preg_replace function (from a script someone else wrote) that adds a `target="_blank"` attribute to all the links. However, when I have a link that already has the `target="_blank"` attribute, it adds another one. This results in a double `target="_blank"` attribute in the link. Is there a way to fix this within the preg_replace function below?

```
$text = preg_replace('%(<a[^>]+)(href="https?://)((?:(?!(' . $host . '))[^"])+|(?:(?=(' . $host . '/' . $base_url . '/))[^"]+))"%i', '$1$2$3"target="_blank"', $text);
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex isn't the good way and very handy for this kind of html manipulations. A prefered way consists to use DOMDocument that is a tool that uses libxml to build a tree of nodes (`DOMNode` instances) from an HTML document. The `DOMNode` class has several usefull methods and properties to do what you want like `hasAttribute` and `setAttribute`:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile('yourhtmlfile.html'); 
// or $dom->loadHTML($htmlContent); //if the html is already in a variable

// get all the link nodes
$linkNodeList = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach($linkNodeList as $linkNode) {
    if (!$linkNode->hasAttribute('target'))
        $linkNode->setAttribute('target', '_blank');
}

$result = $dom->saveHTML();
```

Note: if you want to target a specific domain and base url in the href attribute, you can change the `if` statement to:

```
if ( $linkNode->hasAttribute('target')
  && strpos($host . '/' . $baseurl, $linkNode->getAttribute('href')) !== false)
```

or an other way is to use an XPath query to immediatly target the links you want:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile('yourhtmlfile.html'); 

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

$query = '//a[contains(@href, "' . $host . '/' . $baseurl . '") and not(@target)]';

$linkNodeList = $xp->query($query);

foreach ($linkNodeList as $linkNode) {
    $linkNode->setAttribute('target', '_blank');
}

$result = $dom->saveHTML();
```

Note: If you are working with a partial html document, DOMDocument adds automatically a DTD and creates html and body tags. To prevent this, there are several workarounds:

With PHP >= 5.4 you need to add two options when you load the document:

```
$dom->loadHTMLFile('yourhtmlfile.html', LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);
```

*(sometimes for an unknow reason the constants `LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD` and `LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED` are not defined. In this case you can replace them with their values `4` and `8192`, or define them before, or use directly `8196` that is the result of `4 | 8192`)*

With PHP >= 5.1 the way is to save each body childNodes one by one with `saveXML` and to concatenate the strings:

```
$result = '';
$bodyChildNodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->childNodes;
foreach ($bodyChildNodes as $childNode) {
    $result .= $dom->saveXML($childNode);
}
```

For lower PHP versions, use a string approach:

```
$result = preg_replace('~\A.*?<body>|</body></html>\z~s', '', $result);
```

or

```
$result = explode('<body>', $result, 2);
$result = substr($result[1], 0, -14); // 14 is the string length of "</body></html>"
```

Comment: Thank you, opened my eyes:) I tried it in my code and it works. I used the $text variable to load. Works fine, but it does also output the <html><body> (which i do not need) code tags. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @RobbertT: I have added details about this question.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! one more question: I am using this technique for rel="nofollow" attribute as well. Everything works fine, but i have this variable $follow_list that contains a whitelist of domains (domains that should'nt have the nofollow attribute). The old code for this was:

`$text = preg_replace('%(<a[^>]+)(href="https?://)((?:(?!(' . $host . $follow_list . '))[^"])+|(?:(?=(' . $host . '/' . $base_url . '/))[^"]+))"%i', '$1$2$3" rel="nofollow" ', $text);`

How can i implement this 'check' into the if statement `if (!$linkNode->hasAttribute('rel', 'nofollow')`

any ideas?

Comment: @RobbertT: see the PHP manual to well understand how works the different methods (`hasAttribute`, `getAttribute`, `setAttribute`). If you need to check several url hosts or paths, I suggest you to get href attributes and to use `parse_url` to extract the host and the path. Then you can easily compare them with your list. But if your whitelist isn't to big you can use an XPath query. *(note: it is also possible to use your own php functions inside an XPath query, see manual for details)*

Comment: Thanks! worked! Used this code. Do you think strpos function is suitable here? `$customurl = $linkNode->getAttribute('href');
 $host = parse_url($customurl, PHP_URL_HOST);   
 
 if (!$linkNode->hasAttribute('rel', 'nofollow') && strpos($follow_list,$host) == false )
        $linkNode->setAttribute('rel', 'nofollow');
}`

Comment: @RobbertT: If I were you, I will build `$follow_list` as an array and I will use `in_array` instead. About `strpos`, never write `strpos(...) == false` because `strpos` can return offset 0 that is transtyped to `false` *(so your condition succeeds even if the string is found, indeed `0 == false` is a true condition in PHP)*, always use `strpos(...) === false` that checks the type too.

Comment: all working, thanks. My txt however gets badly formatted now. For instance when i use a ï or é I get symbols like: €™ and  Ã¯. Any idea how to fix this wierd format? Thanks!

Comment: @RobbertT: When you create a DOMDocument instance, you can specify the encoding: `new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');`, however the default parameter is `UTF-8`, this means that the UTF-8 chain is broken somewhere or that an other encoding is used. I suggest you to search one of these tutorials that explains how to use utf8 from begining to end for all without missing a step (database, php, html, code editor ....). Note that you can know what is a string encoding in PHP with `mb_check_encoding` *(one more time the PHP manual is your best friend)*

Comment: My mistake it's `mb_detect_encoding`

Comment: Thank you! this fixed it: `$us_ascii = mb_convert_encoding($text, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
$dom->loadHTML($us_ascii, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD); `

Comment: By the way, is the above code feasible? are there any side effects possible? thank you!

Comment: `$text` seems to be already in UTF8, so don't convert it. I suspect that you haven't `<meta charset="UTF-8"/>` between you `<head>` tags.

Comment: Thank you so much for keep helping me. It's strange, because i do have that in my header `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`. But for some reason it gets wronly encoded. Also, when i use: `echo mb_detect_encoding($text);` it says: ASCII.. but it all should be in utf8 i guess. Tried several websites and servers.